# subversion repository recovery, import and server configuration

Tags: svn, import

After a severe disk failure I managed to recover subversion repository.
My goal is to create a new repository importing on it the old one.

The steps followed are

1. create the folder with the same path as in the previous server:

   svnadmin create /home/svn/myproject
2. Create myuser and add to the group svn, set permissions

   usermod -a -G svn myuser
   chown -R svn:svn /home/svn/myproject/
   chmod -R g+wrs /home/svn/myproject/
3. import from old to new repository

   svn import /old/repository/myproject/ file:///home/svn/myproject/ -m "initial import"

The result of the last command is basically a copy of the folder structure into the new repository.

I thought that at this stage, the above commands would be sufficient to restore the svn functionality.

Indeed it is not the case as using my eclipse client i'm able to connect to the repository but the folders, projects and contents in general are not correctly represented and standard operation are not possible (commit, update, listing folders..).

What's wrong?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly are you going to restore? [Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) or a [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy)?

The command `svn import` will simply do a single commit to the new repository. In other words, the revision history of the project will not be available in the new repository. If you want to restore the complete history of changes, you should either have a dump stream file and [load it using `svnadmin load` / `svnrdump load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) or have a copy of the repository itself (e.g. created using [`svnadmin hotcopy` or any other backup tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup)).